# Android check mobile data and wifi connection

Tags: android, kotlin

I just want to implement a query that checks which WiFi/Mobile settings are enabled every time I click the button. I get weird results with my code.

How can I implement the correct behavior so that I know which adapters are turned on and which are not?

```
private fun check() {
    val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    connectivityManager.run {
        connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)?.run {
            if (hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                Log.d("TAG", "WIFI YES")
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "WIFI NO")
            }

            if (hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                Log.d("TAG", "MOBILE YES")
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "MOBILE NO")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
WiFi   Mobile     --output-->     WiFi     Mobile
```

```
 ×       ×                         no output
 ✓       ×                         yes       no
 ×       ✓                         no        no
 ✓       ✓                         yes       no
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below line of code to check connection according to your requirement you can use it

```
public static boolean isNetworkConnected() {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)TaxiappApplication.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo wifi = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    NetworkInfo mobile = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    NetworkInfo bluetooth = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_BLUETOOTH);
    NetworkInfo wimax = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIMAX);

    if (wifi == null && mobile == null && bluetooth == null && wimax == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (wifi != null && wifi.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    if (mobile != null && mobile.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    if (bluetooth != null && bluetooth.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    if (wimax != null && wimax.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

hope it will help for you